# How do I loop through a data set and perform various actions depending on the contents?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a program that generates data formatted like this.
[image: Sample Data]

I want to pull values from this data and generate text in a text file. I have figured out how to edit the text file, but I am having trouble moving through the data.

```vb
Sub Macro2()
'Declare variables
Dim DIRECTORY As String
Dim SCRPATH As String
Dim COORD As String
Dim PART as String

'Define where txt file is located (it will always be in same location as workbook and have the same name)
DIRECTORY = ActiveWorkbook.Path
SCRPATH = DIRECTORY & "\sample.txt"

'The data being read will always be on the same sheet
With Sheet1

For Each row In Range("A2:A500")
'For each row below the headings, loop through and do the same set of actions
'I have this set as A2:A500 because I know for sure there will never be more than 500 rows of data
'Would it be better to count the rows that have data and then repeat the loop that many times?
'There should never be blank rows breaking up the data

    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
'If there is data in that row, then continue. If there is no data, end the macro

        For Each col In Range("F:J")
            If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
'For every cell with data in the F to J columns, perform an action. When there is no more data, move to the 'next row
                COORD = ActiveCell.Value
'Set COORD to the value of the cell so that it can be printed to the text file
                Open SCRPATH For Append As #1
                Print #1, COORD
                Close #1
            End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

This loops forever, causing Excel to crash. I believe nothing tells the active cell to move.
I would also like to print the value in the "part" cell but am unsure of the best place to put that function.

This is what I would like my output to look like, for all rows of data.
[image: Sample Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using VBA, it's very rare you need to use active cell to get the value.

```vb
Sub Macro2()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, fso, ts, n As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    
    Dim DIRECTORY As String, SCRPATH As String
    DIRECTORY = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    SCRPATH = DIRECTORY & "\sample.txt"
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.createTextFile(SCRPATH)
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            ts.writeline .Cells(i, "B")
            lastcol = .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            For j = 6 To lastcol
                ts.writeline .Cells(i, j)
                n = n + 1
            Next
            ts.writeline ""
            n = n + 2
        Next
    End With
    ts.Close
    
    MsgBox n & " lines written to " & SCRPATH, vbInformation
 
End Sub
```